# How to get android permission call back in unity

Tags: unity, c#, android, permission

I am using unity run time permission system and when i ask for specific permission at run time using this:

> Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

then permission show up.

But now i want get permission callback that has user give the permission or not.
I know that i can check for it using this:

> Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")

But i want some thing more convenient then this.

Comment: Does your application lose focus while the dialog is displayed, and regain focus when the player grants or denies permission? If so, you might be able to make your own pseudo callback via the application focused event.

Comment: When i ask for permission my application is not losing focus. I will appreciate example about pseudo callback?

Comment: Oh i got it thanks for a tip about pseudo callback...

Comment: Oh, did you solve your problem? If so, please post your solution as an answer for others to learn from. :)

Comment: Sure i will do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would love if unity permission has call backs but unfortunately there is not. So i found a way around it.

When i ask for permission using:

> Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

Then android native popup come up which is asking for permission at that time unity application is out of focus. and when user allow or deny permission unity application come back to focus and you can detect when application go out or come int to focus using this:

> OnApplicationFocus(bool){}

So when my application come back to focus then i check for permission if application is allowed or not doing some thing like this:

```
OnApplicationFocus(bool)
{
     if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("Your permission string"))
     {
         Debug.log("Permission Allowed");
     }else
     {
         Debug.log("Permission Denied");
      }
}
```

I hope this will help some in the future. and i am also hoping that unity will implements call backs to android permission.

Spacial Thanks to [@DMGregory♦](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) for helping me out.

Comment: "at that time Unity application is out of focus" — this seems to contradict your comment above, "When I ask for permission my application is not losing focus" — can you clarify what changed? Did you have to do something different to detect the focus change?

Comment: I misunderstood your valuable comment about focus. when i ask for permission application goes out of focus. So after a test i got it. and you were right about it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks, that solution worked for me. But you have to check the `bool` for being `false` as well. It's really weird that Unity even cites the Android best practices of checking for a user denial, but provides no way to do this in a non-hacky way.

Comment: Unity now has callbacks for this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Android.PermissionCallbacks.html

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work.

```
AndroidRuntimePermissions.Permission result = AndroidRuntimePermissions.RequestPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    if (result == AndroidRuntimePermissions.Permission.Granted)
    {
        Debug.Log("We have permission to access external storage!");
        //Do whatever you want to do if permission granted
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Permission state: " + result);
        //Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
```

It will shows request permission automatically and frame will stop until the execution of the request pop up. Then it will check for the permission status. You need to call this lines whenever you need permission.